# What keeps exchanges in modern time from subsuming the role of brokers?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, broker

With the advent of electronic trading, human markets have been mostly replaced, benefiting everyone but the specialists themselves. Why doesn’t modern technology similarly enable exchanges to cut out the brokerages as middlemen and perform some of those same functions themselves?

1. They don't have the organizational capacity. Running an exchange is hard enough; trying to serve a certain investor segment directly will be very difficult for the current management to successfully pull off.
2. Worries about investor’s failure to deliver. Right now, brokers aggregate this risk and do all sorts of things like requiring margins in broker accounts.
3. The SEC just doesn't allow. If so, what regulations exactly?
4. It's not really that lucrative. This would imply that brokers don't make a ton of money, or just that exchanges make a ton more than brokerages.

Are there other reasons? Which are the main ones?

Comment: What question do you think this question answers?  This question is clearly the result of some stream of logic, what's the upstream thought that brought you here?

Comment: @quid Well, computers have all but replaces human market makers, for the benefit of everyone except those specialists themselves. I was wondering why, when it’s technologically easier and more popular than ever to serve mass markets with apps and what not (e.g., Robinhood, others), exchanges haven’t eliminated the broker middleman. Edited my question.

Comment: I don't have any answer to "what regulations exactly", but there would be a clear conflict of interest.  Right now, the exchanges publish information which lets you verify that your broker isn't cheating you.  If one entity were able to tell you what price your order executed at, and also control all access to the information supporting that price, imagine the things that could go wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm… that makes sense! I could imagine there being regulations around that. I know you don’t have more specifics as to the rules, but I wish I could give an upvote for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the business decisions of exchanges aren't related to personal finance.

Comment: @quid The question is meant to be less speculation about an organization, more about the structure of the financial structure, similar to someone asking about how clearing houses work. Would you know if there is a StackOverflow site better dedicated for that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already happened. However, it is not exchanges subsuming brokers, it is brokers creating their own virtual exchanges.  See, for example, [Physical and Virtual Exchanges](http://www.pfhub.com/functioning-of-the-stock-market/#Physical%20and%20Virtual%20Stock%20Exchanges).

One example is BATS [Chi-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BATS_Chi-X_Europe) exchange:

> It is a low latency, low cost alternative to exchange traded equities and exchange-traded funds (ETFs) that are listed on primary exchanges such as the London Stock Exchange, Frankfurt Stock Exchange, Euronext and OMX.

This allows the brokers to avoid paying exchange fees, which, in these days of wafer-thin margins, is a boost to the brokers' profitability.

When they first appeared they were considered quite a threat to the traditional exchanges and they have certainly taken business away from the traditional exchanges.  The traditional exchanges have responded by developing their data analytics offerings and cutting fees.

---

**EDIT**

Yatharth has pointed out in his comment below that my example of BATS owned Chi-X is not the best example I could have given.  (BATS did morph into an exchange operator and is now owned by the legacy exchange CBOE.)

The virtual exchanges I am referring to are called "Alternative Trading Systems" in the US.  Here is a link to the [SEC registered Alternative Trading Systems](https://www.sec.gov/foia/docs/atslist.htm).  The most recent filing (30Nov2018) shows many broker operated ATS such as those operated by Morgan Stanley, Citi, Barclays, UBS, and a host of Johnny-come-latey-s.

These exchanges are sometimes referred to as "Dark Pools". In Europe they are called Multilateral Trading Systems.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense for it to happen the other way, especially for large brokers! Isn’t this similar to a long history of internalization, only more formalized and transparent?

Comment: Regarding the specific BATS Chi-X example, isn’t that just a regular exchange and not a broker (not any more than NASDAQ is)?

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal Please see my edit added to the bottom of my answer.  You're right that BATS was not the clearest of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Exchanges merge but not that frequently.

The powers that be don't like link only replies so here's the link and the acquisition/mergers that have occurred in the past 30+ years:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchange_mergers_in_the_Americas

1986: Intermountain Stock Exchange acquired by Commodity Exchange, Inc. (COMEX).  Intermountain Stock Exchange ceased operating and went dormant

1994: Commodity Exchange merged with New York Mercantile Exchange

1998: Coffee, Sugar and Cocoa Exchange merged with the New York Board of Trade

2005: Pacific Stock Exchange merged with NYSE
Name changed to NYSE Arca

2006: Archipelago acquired by NYSE Euronext

2007: Chicago Board of Trade merged with Chicago Mercantile Exchange
October 2, 2007: Boston Stock Exchange acquired by NASDAQ
Renamed NASDAQ OMX BX

July 24, 2008: Philadelphia Stock Exchange acquired by NASDAQ
Name changed to NASDAQ OMX PHLX

2008: Boston Options Exchange acquired by Montreal Exchange
Name kept as Boston Options Exchange

2008: American Stock Exchange absorbed by NYSE Euronext
Name changed to NYSE Alternext U.S.

2011: National Stock Exchange acquired by CBOE Stock Exchange
Both exchanges kept their separate names.

2014: Direct Edge merged with BATS Global Markets
Name changed to BATS Global Markets

2017: National Stock Exchange acquired by the New York Stock Exchange
National Stock Exchange ceased, with plans to reopen under the NYSE.

2017: BATS Global Markets to be acquired by Chicago Board Options Exchange

Comment: To clarify, I meant why don’t exchanges merge with brokers, not why exchanges don’t merge with each other (which they definitely do!).  Edited my question.